# Ajax Accordion - loading CSS behind code. aspx

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have my accordion databinding as intended however, I have no idea how to load CSS in the behind code.  I have created a new CSS template called Accordion, and placed it under my style folder.

here is the entire contents of my css

```
Header
    {
    background-color: #000000;
   color: White;
   padding: 4px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.SelectedHeader
{
   background-color: #808080;
   color: White;
   padding: 4px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.Contents
{
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Here is my entire accordion behind code

```
AccordionPane currentPane = new AccordionPane();
            currentPane.ID = "AccordionPane" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            currentPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(group.Key.ToString()));

        NavigationAccordion.Panes.Add(currentPane);
        NavigationAccordion.HeaderCssClass = ".Header";
        NavigationAccordion.HeaderSelectedCssClass = ".SelectedHeader";
        NavigationAccordion.ContentCssClass = ".Contents";
        NavigationAccordion.TransitionDuration = 85;
        NavigationAccordion.FramesPerSecond = 200;
        NavigationAccordion.SelectedIndex = -1;
        NavigationAccordion.RequireOpenedPane = false;
        return NavigationAccordion;
```

My guess is I'm not referencing the CSS correctly, but I'm unsure of how to if that's the case.

Thanks!

I have updated my CSS to include `@import "Accordion.css";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem obvious but, are you linking to the Accordian.css file? Ie, in the HTML have the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Accordian.css" />
```

And also you will need to remove the period `.` when assigning the class, as Tim said.

Comment: but its Styles/Accordion.css"

Comment: Then use `href="Styles/Accordian.css"`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the points `.` from your classes:

So for instance instead of

```
NavigationAccordion.ContentCssClass = ".Contents";
```

this

```
NavigationAccordion.ContentCssClass = "Contents";
```

Apart from that i wonder why you need to create them dynamically at all. I assume that this is the reason for your problem. And **you should not create random ID's**, without exception. The ID is important to reload `ViewState` in postbacks and trigger events.

Comment: I actually did try that and it did not pull the css

Comment: Have you pressed `CTRL+F5` to reload the browser-cache?

Comment: Maybe i need to import it somehow?

Comment: Where is the code to load your style reference file for your aspx?

Comment: @Mike: Even if it does not resolve your issue, it would solve your next issue. Why are you creating the AccordionPanes dynamically at all? I assume that this is the (first) reason for your issue. (Edited my answer)

Comment: But OP did not mention whether it is created inside postback condition of outside. Inside case will keep the values.

Comment: @PankajGarg: It doesnt matter when its created since it needs to be recreated on **every** following postback anyway. So it would **never** work to assign random ID's to dynamical controls since they're unpredictable by nature. Apart from the case where it's stored somewhere. But then he should use a static ID instead(f.e. suffixed with an index or an ID from database to be predictable).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried @Tim's solution and it didn't work, check the browser's debugging tool to see if the CSS is present in the page.  It could be an issue with how its being referenced.

Comment: Open your View source, and click the css file reference, if it does not navigates to it's css page. That means issue is in referencing.